# format of a numeric

Tags: sql, db2

I have a problem with the return of my query , I'm using DB2.

Instead of having XX,ZZZ I have XX.ZZZ (eg :12,123 and 12.123 ).Then I have problem in a calclulation inside my main program using the result.

How can I change the numeric format?

Following is the code I am using, and I want to convert "`myTable.myAmount`" to this format XX,ZZZ

Thank you

```
select CASE WHEN myTable.myNb>30 
then myTable.myAmount
ELSE '0' END AS PAR30 from myTable
```

Comment: data type of myAmount column?

Comment: If another system needs the representation changed, you should probably do the conversion over there not in the query.

Comment: myAmount is a float, but my problem is the format, I wanna have this format " 12,123" but the initial format is like this 12.123

Comment: You need to change the locale settings of the table and/or database.  This is something which you should not be trying to handle yourself directly.

Comment: The float data type doesn't have any "format". You may have a problem with format, if you read a float result into a string variable instead of variable of some numeric data type. You do you do this? Doesn't your programming language support float / double / decimal data types?

Comment: Warning: you have a column `myAmount` what you specify is a float.  If `myAmount` stores monetary values, performing math on the results may surprise you!  For best results, store in a base-10 decimal (preferrably fixed-point) type; that is, either `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL`.

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed out before, floats do *not* have a fixed "string" format, they are stored as 16-byte structure in the database which you can examine like this:

```
db2 "values hex(float(0.1))"

1               
----------------
9A9999999999B93F
```

How it will be displayed depends purely on the client. E.g. DB2 CLP will rely on the LOCALE in your environment.

Floats by default are displayed in the scientific notation:

```
db2 "values float(0.1)"

1                       
------------------------
  +1.00000000000000E-001
```

Decimal field separator is the most obvious with the decimal data type:

```
db2 "values decimal(0.1,5,1)"

1      
-------
    0.1
```

Now, I would expect that changing `LC_NUMERIC` to a locale that uses comma as the separator should affect the result, but it doesn't. For DB2 CLP one needs to change LC_ALL (at least based on my quick test). E.g.:

```
export LC_ALL="pl_PL.UTF-8"
db2 connect to sample
db2 "values decimal(0.1,5,1)"

1      
-------
    0,1
```

If you want specific textual format and I don't want Db2 to do the work you can use  [VARCHAR_FORMAT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSCJDQ/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html):

```
db2 "values varchar_format(decimal(0.1,5,1), '990.999')"

1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
--------------
   0.100
```

(or whatever format you want)

Answer (score 0):

So It is solved, I did convertion to int, I don't know why I need to convert a number to a number but it works now.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN myNb > 30 THEN cast(myAmount as INT)
         ELSE '0' END AS PAR30
FROM myTable;
```

Thanks all

Comment: Even here you use different data types in `THEN` (int) and `ELSE` (varchar) data types. It's quite a bad programming style. What data type would you choose for your column, if you where a db2 compiler? Do not do such things, if you don't like surprises...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

```
>db2 "describe select CASE WHEN myTable.myNb>30 then myTable.myAmount ELSE '0' END AS PAR30 from (values (float(1.23), 30)) myTable(myamount, mynb)"

 Column Information

 Number of columns: 1

 SQL type              Type length  Column name                     Name length
 --------------------  -----------  ------------------------------  -----------
 996   DECFLOAT                 16  PAR30                                     5



>db2 "describe select CASE WHEN myTable.myNb>30 then myTable.myAmount ELSE 0 END AS PAR30 from (values (float(1.23), 30)) myTable(myamount, mynb)"

 Column Information

 Number of columns: 1

 SQL type              Type length  Column name                     Name length
 --------------------  -----------  ------------------------------  -----------
 480   DOUBLE                    8  PAR30                                     5
```

The example shows how to get the column data types of a select statement.
The only difference between 2 statements is using `'0'` vs `0` in the `ELSE` clause.
We see, that DB2 uses the `DECFLOAT` data type in the 1-st case and `DOUBLE` in the 2-nd one.
This is probably the root cause of the problem: if an application uses some string variable to get a `DECFLOAT` value (some programming languages / applications may not have an appropriate variable data type for such a database type), then the result depends on local locale / application settings - we may get either `.` or `,` sign as a decimal separator.
But, most programing languages / applications do have an appropriate variable data type for the `DOUBLE` database data type, so, there shouldn't be any problems with it unless one uses a string variable to read such a value still.